# My sql has three cursors, I think it is too much, is there a better way?

Tags: t-sql

here is my code. In db, for each subject, there will be multiple internal courses equivalent to the external courses. The external to internal courses relationship is multiple to multiple, e.g., if a student's transfer transcript has two courses BIOL 101, 102, and 105 from the previous school, the school here will take three of  them and record the student took 103 and 104 here. so my script is to generate a report, list external courses first for each relationship, and then the corresponding internal courses.

I just feel my script has too many cursors(three of them). Is there a better way for this?

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @SUBJECT VARCHAR(5), @SEQ VARCHAR(5);

DECLARE @SCHOOL_SUBJECT VARCHAR(5), @SCHOOL_CRSE_NBR VARCHAR(10), @CRSE_ID VARCHAR(10), @CRSE_OFFER_NBR VARCHAR(10), @COMP_SUBJECT_AREA VARCHAR(5), @BEN_CRSE_ID VARCHAR(10),@BEN_OFFER_NBR VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE SUBJ_SEQ_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT DISTINCT COMP_SUBJECT_AREA, TRNSFR_EQVLNCY_CMP
FROM PS_TRNSFR_COMP A
WHERE A.INSTITUTION='THEINSTITUTION' AND A.TRNSFR_SRC_ID='0222' AND A.EFFDT='2019-06-21'

OPEN SUBJ_SEQ_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM SUBJ_SEQ_CURSOR INTO @SUBJECT, @SEQ

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SUBJECT, @SEQ 

    DECLARE DETAIL_CURSOR_FROM CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT B.SCHOOL_SUBJECT, B.SCHOOL_CRSE_NBR, B.CRSE_ID, B.CRSE_OFFER_NBR 
    FROM PS_TRNSFR_COMP A 
    INNER JOIN PS_TRNSFR_FROM B 
        ON A.INSTITUTION=B.INSTITUTION 
        AND A.TRNSFR_SRC_ID=B.TRNSFR_SRC_ID
        AND A.COMP_SUBJECT_AREA=B.COMP_SUBJECT_AREA
        AND A.TRNSFR_EQVLNCY_CMP=B.TRNSFR_EQVLNCY_CMP
        AND A.EFFDT=B.EFFDT
    WHERE A.INSTITUTION='THEINSTITUTION' AND A.TRNSFR_SRC_ID='0222' AND A.EFFDT='2019-06-21'
    AND A.TRNSFR_EQVLNCY_CMP=@SEQ
    AND A.COMP_SUBJECT_AREA=@SUBJECT

    OPEN DETAIL_CURSOR_FROM
    FETCH NEXT FROM DETAIL_CURSOR_FROM INTO @SCHOOL_SUBJECT, @SCHOOL_CRSE_NBR, @CRSE_ID, @CRSE_OFFER_NBR 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'FROM: ' ,@SCHOOL_SUBJECT, @SCHOOL_CRSE_NBR, @CRSE_ID, @CRSE_OFFER_NBR 

        DECLARE DETAIL_CURSOR_TO CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR 
        SELECT C.COMP_SUBJECT_AREA, C.CRSE_ID, C.CRSE_OFFER_NBR
        FROM PS_TRNSFR_COMP A 
        INNER JOIN PS_TRNSFR_TO C
            ON A.INSTITUTION=C.INSTITUTION
            AND A.TRNSFR_SRC_ID=C.TRNSFR_SRC_ID
            AND A.COMP_SUBJECT_AREA=C.COMP_SUBJECT_AREA
            AND A.TRNSFR_EQVLNCY_CMP=C.TRNSFR_EQVLNCY_CMP
            AND A.EFFDT=C.EFFDT
        WHERE A.INSTITUTION='THEINSTITUTION' AND A.TRNSFR_SRC_ID='0222' AND A.EFFDT='2019-06-21'
        AND A.TRNSFR_EQVLNCY_CMP=@SEQ
        AND A.COMP_SUBJECT_AREA=@SUBJECT

        OPEN DETAIL_CURSOR_TO
        FETCH NEXT FROM DETAIL_CURSOR_TO INTO @COMP_SUBJECT_AREA, @BEN_CRSE_ID, @BEN_OFFER_NBR         

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'TO: ', @COMP_SUBJECT_AREA, @BEN_CRSE_ID, @BEN_OFFER_NBR
            FETCH NEXT FROM DETAIL_CURSOR_TO INTO @COMP_SUBJECT_AREA, @BEN_CRSE_ID, @BEN_OFFER_NBR
        END

        CLOSE DETAIL_CURSOR_TO
        DEALLOCATE DETAIL_CURSOR_TO

        FETCH NEXT FROM DETAIL_CURSOR_FROM INTO @SCHOOL_SUBJECT, @SCHOOL_CRSE_NBR, @CRSE_ID, @CRSE_OFFER_NBR 
    END

    CLOSE DETAIL_CURSOR_FROM
    DEALLOCATE DETAIL_CURSOR_FROM

    FETCH NEXT FROM SUBJ_SEQ_CURSOR INTO @SUBJECT, @SEQ
END

CLOSE SUBJ_SEQ_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE SUBJ_SEQ_CURSOR
```

Comment: I dont think you need any cursor for that, only some good joins. can you add the table structure, sample data, desired output.

Comment: From a pure data retrieval point of view, you could certainly consolidate the SELECT statements. But since you're using this to create a rudimentary report and the nested cursors help you get the output you want in the order you want, I'm wondering if "cleaning up" the data retrieval will make your reporting output more complicated. Is there a performance problem that you're worried about, or do you feel this just isn't "elegant"?

Comment: Thanks Ali and Jeff!

Comment: Yes, I need to create the report to put data in a more user-friendly format.

Comment: I just feel the sql is not elegant, as you said Jeff. So if there is a better way, that would be great.

Comment: I have edited your question to use JOIN-s instead of multiple tables in the FROM clause. I also eliminated some redundant or erroneous conditions. Maybe this should not have been an edit, but I also feel it's not an answer, it's just a step to help you get the answer you need.